# How to find passing argument value of a running script?

Tags: bash, shell, aix

I have an AIX production server, there is a script `A.sh` running on it. 
i have no root access for this server.
i want to find out argument passing value of this `A.sh` script.
How can i get this value?

Is there any provision inside `/proc/processID`?

The following is not working. I tried by generating a script:

```sh
echo "Hello $1 $2 $3"

while [ 1 ]
do
   sleep 2
   echo $$
done
```

Then I run this script by

```
test.sh 1  2 3
```

Output:

```sh
$ cat /proc/3107/cmdline
-bash$
```

As per suggestion by @Cyrus  suggestion I expect

```
1 2 3
```

which are the arguments I passed in, but it is not working like that.

Comment: On SO we do encourage people to post their efforts in their questions, so kindly do add it in your post and let us know then.

Comment: AIX. Why do you use `linux` tag?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus  i want to run on both ubuntu and IBM AIX. in ubuntu for testing purpose.

Comment: Off: this is the reason why program should overwrite their parameters if they contain confidental data (passwords).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
cat /proc/PROCESSID/cmdline
```

Comment: I suggest to append `| tr '\0' ' '`.

Comment: To exactly get the parameters, exclude the calling program by appending `| cut -d ' ' -f  3-`  from the `tr` piped output as told by @Cyrus. For e.g., `cat /proc/$(pgrep -f test.sh)/cmdline | tr '\0' ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f  3-`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
cat /proc/3107/cmdline | tr '\0' ' ';
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
ps -ef | grep script.sh | grep -v grep
```

where `script.sh` is the name of your script which is running now.

**Steps for verifying this:**

1. Create a script named script.sh and paste the below code in it:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   while :
   do
     echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
     sleep 1
   done
   ```
2. Save the file (`:wq!` from vi editor ).
3. Make it executable by

   ```
   chmod a+x script.sh
   ```
4. Run the script by issuing command-line options like this:

   ```
   ./script.sh var1 val1 var2 val2 var2 val4
   ```
5. Open another terminal (duplicate session) and issue:

   ```
   ps -ef | grep script.sh | grep -v grep
   ```

You should be able to see something like this:

```
username 12227  2268  0 07:48 pts/98   00:00:00 /bin/bash ./script.sh var1 val1 var2 val2 var2 val4 var4
```

Comment: Oh ok, which means your process is not running. Do you see the exit status 1 after issuing the above command? (You can run echo $? to check the exit code). I have updated the steps for creating the script and testing it. You can follow that.

Comment: @ https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218985/sarath-kumar-sivan  this is working in ubuntu but not know about AIX server. Is this solution is worked on AIX IBM ?